# How to make a list of private slots in Qt?

Tags: qt, qlist

A nice simple example would be nice. For my part, I have about 200 unique slots that I would like to append into a list, and then setup various connections using an iterating "for" loop.

Answer (score 4):

To retrieve the signature of QObject's methods (signals, slots, etc.) you can use meta object (`QMetaObject`) information. For example the following code (taken from Qt documentation) extracts all methods' signatures of the object:

```
const QMetaObject* metaObject = obj->metaObject();
QStringList methods;
for(int i = metaObject->methodOffset(); i < metaObject->methodCount(); ++i) {
    if (metaObject->method(i).methodType() == QMetaMethod::Slot) {
        methods << QString::fromLatin1(metaObject->method(i).signature());
    }
}
```

To check whether the method is a slot or a signal, you can use `QMetaMethod::methodType()` function. For signature use `QMetaMethod::signature()` (refer to the example above).

[QMetaObject reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html)

Comment: you are handling ALL methods not only slots. `methodType` value for `method(i)` should be verified.

Comment: @MarekR, although I mentioned the usage of QMetaMethod::methodType(), anyways, I have updated the sample code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This response was offered to me on a forum. I am posting it here for reference:

```
QList<const char*> slotList;
slotList << SLOT(slot1());
slotList << SLOT(slot2());
// ...

for(int i=0; i< listOfButtons.size();++i) {
connect(listOfButtons->at(i), SIGNAL(clicked()), this, slotList.at(i));
}
```

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56224-A-list-for-storing-member-functions-slots

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a class's [QMetaObject](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html) using [QObject::metaObject()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#metaObject) method.
2. Retrieve a number of all methods with [QMetaObject::methodCount()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#methodCount).
3. Iterating through all method indexes use [QMetaObject::method()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#method) to get [QMetaMethod](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetamethod.html).
4. With [QMetaMethod::methodType()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetamethod.html#methodType) it is possible to check if method is slot.
5. Add signatures ([QMetaMethod::signature()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetamethod.html#signature)) of slots to list for later use in `connect()`.